# When these two elements will be equal : nearest element to average vs median?

Tags: average, median

I understand that **median** element is calculated based on index/total number of elements in an Array while Average is based on total value of the array.
I am trying to solve the question :
Given an integer K and a matrix of N rows and M columns, the task is to find the minimum number of operations required to make all the elements of the matrix equal. In a single operation, K can be added to or subtracted from any element of the matrix.

> Which element we should take here (to which all the elements will be
>   made equal) and why?

Comment: The matrix doesn't matter, it is just a list of $MN$ terms.  How about trying some small lists, like $(1,8), (1,1,1,6)$ and see if you see any pattern?  All the differences between elements better be divisible by $K$ or you will never succeed.

Comment: @RossMillikan Exactly; and this would be true no matter whether we take median element say x or element nearest to Average say y. What I really want to understand is converting every element of M*N series/array,to which element out of x and y will require minimum changes?

Comment: That is why I suggested you try the small cases.  Note that $(1,1,1,6)$ has a median of $1$ and an average of $\frac 32$.  Maybe $(1,1,1,13)$ would be better because the average is $4$.

Comment: (1,1,1,13) average comes 4 and the nearest element to average would be 1, so is the median. Okay! Let me try with more examples and see if these two values can differ.